# Wifi is not working on Lenevo G50-70 UBUNTU 14.04 LTS and no harware detection

Tags: wireless

I have tried too many to tutorials but not get success to enable wifi.
By using `rfkill` I am getting info about bluetooth not for Wlan.

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
>>  Soft blocked: no
>>  Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to view your Wifi device. Example taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240673&page=2

```
danielmartin@danielmartin-Lenovo-G50-70:~$ sudo lshw | grep [Ww]ireless ; sudo lspci | grep [wW]ireless
[sudo] password for danielmartin: 
description: Wireless interface
product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.13.0-34-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.72 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
danielmartin@danielmartin-Lenovo-G50-70:~$
```

There are also temporary and permanent fixes you can do quoted from the same thread.

A temp fix is to run:

```
sudo rmmod rtl8723be && modprobe rtl8723be
```

If this works, you can make it automatic by creating a conf file as follows -

```
touch Desktop/modules
```

This will create a file named "modules" on your Desktop. Now open it with your text editor, and put (copy-paste) the following line in it -

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES rtl8723be"
```

Proofread, save and close the file. Now copy it to the location where it should be -

```
sudo cp Desktop/modules /etc/pm/config.d
```

Reboot > suspend > resume, and let us know if it worked. Basically, it tries to do the same thing as the combination of the rmmod/modprobe commands sotiris2 suggested, only automatically and elegantly.

Comment: Not working i have followed all steps.
>deep@deep-Lenovo-G50-70:~$ sudo lshw | grep [Ww]ireless ; sudo lspci | grep [wW]ireless

>deep@deep-Lenovo-G50-70:~$